# background image or color for a static box in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

anyone knows how we can set an image or color for the background in a static box in vc++

Comment: You know that VC++ is a development environment and/or a C++ compiler, but not a GUI toolkit? Guess you mean MFC or ATL? Or a dialog resource?

Comment: ya mfc...a static box inside a dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Derive your own class from CStatic, and override OnCtlColour

Here you got the docs + a sample.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0wwk06hc.aspx

I am not sure if this works for images also, but you know where to look.